# Fragment spinner doesn't stop in Android

Tags: android

I use this code to load the nearby places of any particular location by setting the** data using an Array Adapter. There are two issues that I face:
1. The spinner doesn't stop even after the data is loaded. (There should be no spinner. But I am not sure how does Fragment when it comes to this.)

1. I'm going to implement AsyncTask to get the places so that it doesn't slow down the Activity. The mini problem I face is this: How do I notify the user (update the view) with new date when he/she has changed his location. Let's assume that that the user is walking. Thus the lat/lon will change. So, how can I use onChangeNotify() and change the value of the List.

   public class FragmentMap extends ListFragment  {

   ```
       ArrayList<Place> places = new ArrayList<Place>();
       //List<String> val = new List<String>()
       //@InjectView(R.id.explorePlacesListView) ListView placesListView;
       ListView listView;
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


       }

       @Override
       public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


               ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.explorePlacesListView);
           getPlaces();

           PlacesAdapter placesAdapter = new PlacesAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.user_list_item, places);
           listView.setAdapter(placesAdapter);
       }



       public void getPlaces(){

            URL yahoo;
            String key,latitude,longitude;
            key = "AIzaSyAZgD01sj3jssaYCmkLL8c7Z4qPTEdt6xU";
            latitude = "37.77264";
            longitude ="-122.409915";
           try {

               yahoo = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyB2SGEmOLDGB_f0bp1PGTjQqTw2VuDcaM8");
               URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
               BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                       new InputStreamReader(
                                       yc.getInputStream()));
               String inputLine;
               String jsonLine = new String();
               while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                       Log.d("inputLine",inputLine);

                       jsonLine = jsonLine + inputLine;
           }
               in.close();
               Object jsonResponse = parseResponse(jsonLine);
               parseJSONPlaces((JSONObject)jsonResponse);
           } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (JSONException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

       }

       protected Object parseResponse(String responseBody) throws JSONException {
           return new JSONTokener(responseBody).nextValue();
       }

    private void parseJSONPlaces(JSONObject json){

        try {
       JSONArray jsonArray =   json.getJSONArray("results");

       for (int j = 0; j < json.length(); j++) {

           Place place = new Place();


           place.name = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("name");
           place.icon = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("icon");
          // JSONObject locationObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("location");
          // place.latitude = locationObject.getString("latitude");
          // place.longitude = locationObject.getString("longitude");
           Log.d("name",place.name);

           places.add(place);
       }
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
         if(json.optJSONObject("results") != null){


           }



    }
   ```

Comment: Do you mean a "busy" indicator when you say "Spinner"?

Comment: No. I mean a spinner. No text. No nothing. Just a spinning thing next to text.

Comment: No, actually, you aren't talking about a spinner.  A spinner in android is a drop down list chooser widget (which is why I asked, as your question makes no sense in relationship to an Android spinner).  You are talking about a Progress Bar, and unfortunately I haven't had occasion to use one so I know nothing about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things in your code that looks a bit strange to me.

You never call `setListAdapter()` which binds an adapter to the internal ListView of the ListFragment. Instead, you are fetching another ListView and set an adapter to that one. That is probably why no data gets displayed in the list, and you will instead se a progress indicator.

I'm not sure I understand your second question, but you should put your UI updates in the onPostExecute method of AsychTask.

Comment: Yes. I got the mistake. So, do I have to over ride the List Fragment to insert this list?

Comment: You are already extending ListFragment, so I would guess that your own listView is unnecessary. Have a look at the [ListFragment docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) and google for some examples, for instance [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Core-Class/DemonstrationofusingListFragmenttoshowalistofitemsfromacannedarray.htm)

Comment: If you want to provide your own custom view, check out onCreateView

Comment: The problem is that the examples deal with List Adapters and not Array Adapter. I want to push data into a list View using Array Adapters.

Comment: Well, the example I linked to actually uses ArrayAdapter.